# Google Script error during batch execution

Tags: csv, google-apps-script

I'have a problem with a google script.

This script does:

- opens a spreadsheet
- cleans his content
- opens a csv file
- copy csv file content into the spreadsheet

Scheduling it I obtain this error:
Nessun elemento trovato con l'ID specificato o non disponi di autorizzazioni per accedervi. (riga 172, file "Codice")

The meaning is: 
"No element found with the specified id or no authorization to access"

The row number 172 contain this line:

```
var file=DriveApp.getFileById(idCsvRicevute);
```

the variable idCsvRicevute contain the id of the csv file as string ("idnumber").

I did:

- checked if the csv file has the right id: ok
- tried to open it to view the content: ok (no authentication required)
- tried to open it using google spreadsheet to edit it: ok (no
  authentication required)
- tried to execute the script manually: **ok it works**

The error appears **only when the script is scheduled**.

Can you please address me to understand the differences (if existent) between the manual execution vs. the batch excecution?
If no differences, what could be the problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does that line run more than once?  Like in a loop?

Comment: @SandyGood: the line is executed one time every execution.

Comment: @Cooper: There isn't any button or dialog inside the spreadsheet. The script is contained in a specific file and is scheduled one time by night.

Comment: That error code may be erroneous.  The code may be producing an error because it is hitting a quota limit.  If a service is invoked many times in rapid succession, you could get an error. The simplies thing you can do is to put a `Utilities.sleep(milliseconds)` pause in the code.  There are other ways to slow down the code.  You could try making the code pause with a `sleep` method and if that makes a difference, then the cause could be that the service is running to rapidly in succession.